# How to block an erlang process until a network connection becomes available

Tags: mobile, synchronization, erlang

I am setting up a sort of syncing mechanism between two different erlang nodes (on 2 different machines or devices). One of these devices will be disconnected from the network to accomplish another task.

When the device is reconnected to the network, it needs to contact the other erlang node to initiate data syncing.

Is there a way in erlang to receive a message when the network connection is available? Or would I have to do some sort of polling.

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to node connection changes through `net_kernel:monitor_nodes/1`. This will send you `{nodeup, Node}` and `{nodedown, Node}` messages you can use to drive your own sync logic.

You would probably want a process that regularly runs `net_adm:ping(TargetNode)` to try to connect to the other node so that would would then get the `{nodeup, TargetNode}` messages. This would avoid needing to explicitly check OS network availability via polling (the undocumented) `inet:getiflist/0` for changes.